# Check messages posted to queue in jBoss

Tags: jboss, queue, jms, jmx

Hi I have added this code

```
    <mbean code="org.jboss.mq.server.jmx.Queue"
         name="jboss.mq.destination:service=Queue,name=myQueue">
<depends optional-attribute-name="DestinationManager">jboss.mq:service=DestinationManager</depends>
</mbean>
```

to my /server/default/deploy/jms/jbossmq-destinations-service.xml

The queue works fine...
but where do i see the messages posted to the queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [jmx-console](http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/) to view the messages in a queue. What you should look at is `jboss.messaging.destination` on the left hand side. If you can't find it, use `jboss.messaging.destination:*` as the objectfilter and search.

Once you find your Queue, you can see attribute `MessageCount` that shows your the current messages in the queue.